# Filebeat Timestamp Processor Parses Timestamp Incorrectly

Tags: filebeat

Given the following datetime in the log: **2023-05-04T17:26:29.369+03:00**

And the following timestamp processor config:

```
- timestamp:
    field: logRecord.timestamp
    target_field: hello
    layouts:
      - '2006-01-02T15:04:06.999+03:00'
      - '2006-01-02T15:04:06.999Z'
```

The resulting hello field is the following:
"hello":"2029-05-04T03:26:00.369Z"

The question - why does it apply such huge offset (-14 hours) - shouldn't it take one from the source timestamp itself (+03:00) and the result should be **2023-05-04T14:26:29.369Z**

Could someone help please? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It was my fault - Filebeat is written in Go and date patterns are using digits (e.g. month is denoted as 01). So the pattern was incorrect.